# I have a linkbutton and I need to focus it after hitting the enter key in a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a linkbutton and I need to focus it after hitting the enter key in a textfield, I've tried many times to put a .focus () by id, href, by class and didn't find a way that would work

Answer (score 0):

Rough draft but illustrates the point.

```js
$(function() {
    $('input').keypress(function(event){
      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
      if(keycode == '13'){
          $('button').focus();
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="50" />

<button type="button">Focus on Me</button>
```

Resource:
https://howtodoinjava.com/jquery/jquery-detect-if-enter-key-is-pressed/

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI in pure JavaScript if it helps someone:

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button id="button">Focus on me</button>
```

```js
input.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') button.focus();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vgtsky/rxatjo7e/1/)

And try to not use:

- [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)
- [`charCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode)
- [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which)

'cause they are already deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a keyup event and then you will can focus the element.

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("send").focus();
  }
});

<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #send {
      background: white;
      border: 1px solid #0061AA; 
      color: #0061AA;
      border-radius:2px;
      padding:5px 10px;
    }
    #send:focus {
      background: #0061AA;
      color:white;
      border: 1px solid #0061AA; 
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="form" >
    <input type="button" id="send" value="Send"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nums2etb/7/